# Selecting the specific row and column next to the cell

Tags: image, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to make API requests w/ a custom function I found on github. The function works fine but I am attempting to select a specific value from a cell, and input that into a URL which will be requested, the code looks like this:

```
=IMAGE(CONCATENATE("https://www.roblox.com/bust-thumbnail/image?userId=",F,ROW(),"&width=48&height=48&format=png"))
```

Now as you can see I am doing pretty miserably at pulling the appropriate row, though the column is fine, It's just constantly F, but how do I specify the current row correctly so this works?

Comment: My error is coming up as ```Unknown range name: 'F'.```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IMAGE("https://www.roblox.com/bust-thumbnail/image?userId="&
 ROW()&"&width=48&height=48&format=png")
```

[image: 0]

---

if you want to refer number from column F then it would be:

```
=IMAGE("https://www.roblox.com/bust-thumbnail/image?userId="&
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), 6))&"&width=48&height=48&format=png")
```

[image]